# Comma separated list from array with "and" before last element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array (`$number_list`) that has a dynamically generated list of values. There will be at least 1 value in the array and no more than 4.

Currently, I have a nice way of having a comma separated list using this...

```
$comma_list = implode(', ', $number_list);
```

However, I'd like to keep with English convention and have the word "and" before the last element.  So, let's say $number_list contains the values 4, 5, 6, 7.  I would want to echo a statement like, "The list is 4, 5, 6, **and** 7."

Any ideas how to get that **and** in there?

Comment: $comma_list is an array, so the count() function can perfectly fit to tell you how many elements does it have. You need to find the pre-last element ( count($comma_list)-1 ) and append `and` after it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `array_pop()` to get the last element, then `array_push` to modify and push the element back:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

Something like

```
$last_element = array_pop($number_list);
array_push($number_list, 'and '.$last_element);
```

Then you can do your implode:

```
$comma_list = implode(', ', $number_list);
```

Comment: Nice idea, but this will place an Oxford comma before "and".

Comment: @Jon - Which is exactly what he wanted in his original question.

Comment: Problem with this solution is an array with 0 or 1 element only. So better add code that checks for those cases where it does not work.

Comment: For those who don't want the Oxford comma, you can do like this:
$number_list = Array(1,2,3,4,5);
$last_element = array_pop($number_list);
echo implode(', ', $number_list) . ' and ' . $last_element;

Answer (score 18):

Remove the last element from the list, implode what's left with commas and then concatenate "and last_element":

```
$last = array_pop($number_list);
$output = implode(', ', $number_list);
if ($output) {
    $output .= ', and ';
}
$output .= $last;
```

If you prefer, you can also write the above more tersely as

```
$last = array_pop($number_list);
$output = $number_list
    ? implode(', ', $number_list).', and '.$last
    : $last;
```

**Update:**

I have to admit I initially misread the question and thought that it was about *replacing* the last comma with "and", not *adding* an "and" before the final item. I have since edited the answer to target the latter scenario. Note that the code can be easily adapted to do either by selecting `" and "` or `", and "` for the "glue" string respectively.

Comment: Concatenation for `$output` is reversed. I cannot edit this as not enough characters changed, but just watch out for that. Good answer! `.=` vs `=.`

Answer (score 4):

If the list has at least two elements at the end, you can implode them with `" and "` (or if your question wasn't borked `", and "`) already.

Then you implode the whole array with `", "`.

- http://php.net/array_splice

Example:

```
<?php

$numbers = range(1, 4);

array_splice($numbers, -2, 2, implode(' and ', array_slice($numbers, -2)));

echo implode(', ', $numbers); prints "1, 2, 3 and 4"
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/DHPla

Comment: The eval.in link is dead. Unless mutating `$numbers` is a concern, this looks reliable to me. https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/f7f2b5d7bfa0eabed7c275ffbb77b671/

Comment: @mickmackusa thx for the hint & link updated to 3v4l.org. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$number_list = array(4, 5, 6, 7);    
$comma_list = strrev(implode(strrev(', and'), explode(strrev(','), strrev(implode(', ', $number_list)), 2)));
echo 'The list is ' . $comma_list . '.';
```

Output:
The list is 4, 5, 6, and 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
# pop the last element off the array and formate text
if( count( $number_list )>1 ){
    $and = " and ".array_pop( $number_list );
}else{
    $and = '';
}
# Implode number list , and  append $and
$comma_list = implode(', ', $number_list).$and;
```

Answer (score 0):

[strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

```
<?php

$number_list= Array(1,2,3,4,5);
$comma_list = implode(', ', $number_list);
$comma_list = substr($comma_list,0,strrpos($comma_list,',')).' And'.substr($comma_list,strrpos($comma_list,',')+1);
echo $comma_list;
//returns 1, 2, 3, 4 And 5
?>
```